# Developing for Android on Windows 7 using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7

I have followed all the necessary installation and setup steps for `Eclipse 3.4 + ADT + Android SDK` on **Windows 7**.

I followed the Hello, Android tutorial in Eclipse and code-completion also works like a charm. No errors shown.

unfortunately the emulator never shows up.

When I run the project. I have fullfilled the same steps in a virtual Windows XP machine and - though very slow - it does work there.

I have not found anything about known problems with `Windows 7`. What can I do?

Comment: Voted to close/migrate to superuser, as this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Note that Windows 7 does not meet the system requirements: http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Comment: Indeed Win7 is not one of the supported operating systems, but mainly it works without any problems. I have Win7 x86 and i had no problems. If it still won't work you could try Win7 Xp Mode, it won't run that slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try launching the emulator from the command line with the `-verbose` option as this may help determine why it is failing:

```
emulator -verbose -avd <avd name>
```

To a get a list with the names of AVDs you've set up enter:

```
android list avd
```

(If nothing shows up when you list your AVDs that's your problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are running the app as an android app and as Dave Webb suggest ensure you have an emulator "profile" created.  I created one to meet my HTC Hero and I use Windows 7 (x64).

NOTE: You might also want to unplug your HTC device, if its connected to the PC.  I've noticed that if its plugged in the apps will download and run directly on the real device.  Thats probably by design and intentional. ;-)

HTH

Philip

Answer (score 0):

I am developing on Windows 7 Pro with no issues. Eclipe and Emulator are all working OK.